# Nginx handle 500 internal server error security issue

Tags: security, nginx, lua, zap, custom-error-handling

I am trying to fix a security vulnerability of 500 internal server error disclose location of the file

My issue is similar to that of (https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*2DAwIEJhgLQd82t5WTgydA.png)

(https://medium.com/volosoft/running-penetration-tests-for-your-website-as-a-simple-developer-with-owasp-zap-493d6a7e182b)

I am tried with

> proxy_intercept_errors on;

and

> error_page 500

redirection but it didnt help.

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of implementing `proxy_intercept_errors on;`

```
upstream foo {
    server unix:/tmp/foo.sock;
    keepalive 60;
}

server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location = /errors/5xx.html {
        internal;
        root /tmp;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://foo;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 404 =200 /errors/5xx.html;   
    }
}
```

Notice the:

```
error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 404 =200 /errors/5xx.html;
```

This will intercept some `5xx` errors and the `404` except and return with a 200

Also, check the `/errors/5xx.html` location, is using `root /tmp;` therefore you still need to create the file `errors/5xx.html`:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/errors
$ echo "intercepting errors" > /tmp/errors/5xx.hml
```

You don't necessarily need to a file to reply you request you could also use something like this:

```
location = /errors/5xx.html {
    internal;
    default_type text/plain;
    return 200 'Hello world!';
}
```

In your case the `404` File not found could be handle different, for example:

```
upstream failover{
    server server2:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /tmp/test;

    location ~* \.(mp4)$ {
        try_files $uri @failover;
    }

    location @failover {
        proxy_pass http://failover;
    }
}
```

In this case if the file ending with `.mp4` not found it will try another server, then if required you still can intercep the error there.

Comment: upvoting it. Can i just make my 500 internal server error as 200 is it possible ?

Comment: @Hari, yes, I updated the example with status code `500`, you indeed other status codes as well.

Comment: Why disguise the issue? If you're hitting 500s then obviously there's some sort of input you haven't anticipated. Hiding the 500 by faking a 200 doesn't mean that your preventing the potential DoS or failure.